# Python - How to query DynamoDB on GSI using primary and sort key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Well, as the title suggest I want to query on my DynamoDB table using GSI with the primary key and sort key (both from the GSI). I tried some ways to do it, but any success.

I have a table with the `url-date-index`, the `url` is the primary key from from the GSI, and the `date` is the sort key.

I tried the following:

1. Using `KeyConditionExpression` with `&` comparator:

   This one retrieved me the error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like`

```py
boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table').query(
    IndexName='url-date-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key('url')).eq(url) & conditions.Key('date')).eq(date)
)
```

2. Using `KeyConditionExpression` and `FilterExpression`:

   This retrieved the following error: `Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes`

```py
boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table').query(
    IndexName='url-date-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key('url')).eq(url),
    FilterExpression=conditions.Key('date')).eq(date)
)
```

3. Using `ExpressionAttributeNames`, `ExpressionAttributeValues` and `KeyConditionExpression`:

   This returned anything, even not the item that matches the `url` and `date` on the table.

```py
boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table').query(
    IndexName='url-date-index',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#n0': 'url',
        '#n1': 'date'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':v0': url,
        ':v1': date
    },
    KeyConditionExpression='(#n0 = :v0) AND (#n1 = :v1)'
)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular use-case, you'll want to use `ExpressionAttributeNames` since your attribute names `url` and `date` are [reserved words in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.ReservedWords).

The [DynamoDB docs on querying secondary idnexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.scenario) gives an example of a properly structured query, which we can apply to your situation:

Using this as a guide, we can construct what the arguments to your query operation should look like.  For example

```
 {
    "TableName": "table",
    "IndexName": "url-date-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#pk = :pk And #sk = :sk",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#pk":"url","#sk":"date"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":pk": {"S":url},":sk": {"S":date}}}
}
```

If this still doesn't work for you, consider checking out the [NoSQL Workbench For DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html).  Among it's many useful features, it has an Operation Builder that helps you construct DynamoDB operations using a graphical interface. You can even run the operation against your live database.  Once you have the operation working as you want, the tool can then translate the operation into a complete Phython, Javascript(Node) or Java code sample, which you can use to see how the operation is constructed.

Comment: It worked! I just don't understand why since it's basically the same thing as the 3rd example I showed.

Comment: Great!  Your example did not include types in the ExpressionAttributeValues.   Notice how I'm defining `url` and `date` as strings

Comment: Aah that makes sense! Thank you by helping me!

Answer (score 1):

[query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query) is a function with some named arguments (`IndexName`, `KeyConditionExpression`, ...).

Let's try to call the function with named arguments as a normal function:

```
boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table').query(
    IndexName='url-date-index', 
    KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key('url')).eq(url) & conditions.Key('date')).eq(date)
)
```

Comment: Owch, I saw that I've put the wrong syntax on the question, working with more than one language program can cause that lol. Actualy, I've used the correct syntax in my code. I'll fix it now. Btw, thanks